# Django Tutorial part 2 Field Error

Tags: django

I got a field error when I was trying to run the tutorial of Django Part 2. I'm using Python 3.6 and Django 1.11.

models.py

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Working with the tutorial, step by step. I was running the `python manage.py shell`:

```
>>> from polls.models import Question, Choice

>>> Question.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Question: What's up?>]>
>>> Question.objects.filter(id=1)
<QuerySet [<Question: What's up?>]>
>>> Question.objects.filter(question_text__startswith='What')
```

I got the following error after `Question.objects.filter(question_text__startswith='What')`:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'question_text_startswith' into field. Choices are: choice, id, pub_date, question_text
```

I don't know what to do to repair this error, maybe I put something wrong at models, that's why I share `models.py` with you. I hope you can help me

Comment: The error states clearly that `startswith` is not preceded by two underscores. Check this.

Comment: `'question_text_startswith'` should be `'question_text__startswith'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have 2 underscores before startswith.

Try

```
Question.objects.filter(question_text__startswith='What')
```

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck for a while there :)